# How to exchange Msgpack files between Python and R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, tibble, msgpack

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = pd.DataFrame({'mytime': [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 10:00:00.513'),
                                pd.to_datetime('2018-01-03 10:00:00.513')],
                      'myvariable': [1,2],
                      'mystring': ['hello', 'world']})
mydata
Out[7]: 
  mystring                  mytime  myvariable
0    hello 2018-01-01 10:00:00.513           1
1    world 2018-01-03 10:00:00.513           2
```

I know I can write that dataframe to `msgpack` using `Pandas`:

```
mydata.to_msgpack('C://Users/john/Documents/mypack')
```

The problem is: how can I read that `msgpack` file in `R`?

Using `RcppMsgPack` returns some puzzling output that is not a `dataframe`/`tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RcppMsgPack)

df <- msgpack_read('C://Users/john/Documents/mypack', simplify = TRUE)
 > df
$axes
$axes[[1]]
$axes[[1]]$typ
[1] "index"

$axes[[1]]$name
NULL

$axes[[1]]$klass
[1] "Index"

$axes[[1]]$compress
NULL

$axes[[1]]$data
[1] "mystring"   "mytime"     "myvariable"

$axes[[1]]$dtype
[1] "object"


$axes[[2]]
$axes[[2]]$typ
[1] "range_index"

$axes[[2]]$name
NULL

$axes[[2]]$klass
[1] "RangeIndex"

$axes[[2]]$start
[1] 0

$axes[[2]]$step
[1] 1

$axes[[2]]$stop
[1] 2



$typ
[1] "block_manager"

$blocks
$blocks[[1]]
$blocks[[1]]$shape
[1] 1 2

$blocks[[1]]$klass
[1] "IntBlock"

$blocks[[1]]$compress
NULL

$blocks[[1]]$values
 [1] 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
attr(,"EXT")
[1] 0

$blocks[[1]]$locs
$blocks[[1]]$locs$typ
[1] "ndarray"

$blocks[[1]]$locs$dtype
[1] "int64"

$blocks[[1]]$locs$compress
NULL

$blocks[[1]]$locs$ndim
[1] 1

$blocks[[1]]$locs$data
[1] 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
attr(,"EXT")
[1] 0

$blocks[[1]]$locs$shape
[1] 1


$blocks[[1]]$dtype
[1] "int64"


$blocks[[2]]
$blocks[[2]]$shape
[1] 1 2

$blocks[[2]]$klass
[1] "DatetimeBlock"

$blocks[[2]]$compress
NULL

$blocks[[2]]$values
 [1] 40 02 0e 64 4d a7 05 15 40 02 ac 86 76 44 06 15
attr(,"EXT")
[1] 0

$blocks[[2]]$locs
$blocks[[2]]$locs$typ
[1] "ndarray"

$blocks[[2]]$locs$dtype
[1] "int64"

$blocks[[2]]$locs$compress
NULL

$blocks[[2]]$locs$ndim
[1] 1

$blocks[[2]]$locs$data
[1] 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
attr(,"EXT")
[1] 0

$blocks[[2]]$locs$shape
[1] 1


$blocks[[2]]$dtype
[1] "datetime64[ns]"


$blocks[[3]]
$blocks[[3]]$shape
[1] 1 2

$blocks[[3]]$klass
[1] "ObjectBlock"

$blocks[[3]]$compress
NULL

$blocks[[3]]$values
[1] "hello" "world"

$blocks[[3]]$locs
$blocks[[3]]$locs$typ
[1] "ndarray"

$blocks[[3]]$locs$dtype
[1] "int64"

$blocks[[3]]$locs$compress
NULL

$blocks[[3]]$locs$ndim
[1] 1

$blocks[[3]]$locs$data
[1] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
attr(,"EXT")
[1] 0

$blocks[[3]]$locs$shape
[1] 1


$blocks[[3]]$dtype
[1] "object"



$klass
[1] "DataFrame"
```

What should I do?

Of course, going back from R to Python would also be nice. Thanks!

Comment: its super long. let me see if I can do it

Comment: @Parfait done my man\

Comment: Yes, looks to be Pythonic elements: *dtype*, *ndarray*.... Curious, how does the same R data with *msgpack* look? And can it be read in Pandas?

Comment: @Parfait its an interesting point. I dont know. But maybe we can get started with that side of the equation first :)

Comment: Apparently, the `msgpack` representation of a `pandas` DataFrame is very low level, so it cannot translate as is to an R suitable object. Either you write some code which converts the `RcppMsgPack` output to an R data.frame or you change the process that produces the `msgpack` file. This latter solution is of course way better: it's a very bad practice to produce output which can only be read with a specific language.

Answer (score 1):

How about you use `library(reticulate)` in R:

```
library(reticulate)
pyData = py_run_string("import pandas as pd
mydata = pd.DataFrame({'mytime': [pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01 10:00:00.513'),
                                pd.to_datetime('2018-01-03 10:00:00.513')],
                      'myvariable': [1,2],
                      'mystring': ['hello', 'world']})")
```

It would yield the desired output:

```
pyData$mydata
    mystring              mytime myvariable
1    hello 2018-01-01 10:00:00          1
2    world 2018-01-03 10:00:00          2
```

You could save all the python code in a python file, e.g. `mydata.py` and use the function `py_run_file("mydata.py")`.

An overview of `reticulate` can be found here: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate.

Most interesting for you is probably the description of the type conversions:

[image]
Source: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate#type-conversions.

**Add-on question - From R to Python:**

The type conversion also holds for "sending" data from R to Python, see here: https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/articles/calling_python.html#sourcing-scripts.

```
py = py_run_string("def add(x, y):
  return x + y")

py$add(5, 10)
15
```

Comment: interesting but I need a pure R solution

Comment: This is a pure R solution. It uses one R package. Yes, it interfaces with a language but so do other R packages that uses RCpp (C++)  or RJava!

Comment: no, unfortunately `reticulate` does not work with my network setup (I cant get that package to work correctly). So I am looking for something that leverages the `msgpack` packages in R.

Comment: also, that solution does not address the `msgpack` Python/R compatibility issue at all.

Comment: Tough! This bypasses I/O needs of reading/writing to and from disk.

Comment: thats the point of my question bro! computer A generates the msgpack in Python and computer B reads it in R.